# How to show a given Riemann metric in a Euclidean space being incomplete?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

When working out the question in Do Carmo, I encounter a problem to show a given Riemannian manifold is incomplete. The given metric is $$g_{ij}=\frac{\delta_{ij}}{(1+\frac{K}{4}\sum x_i^2)^2}$$ defined on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Where $K>0$ is a constant.

I have no idea of the approaches to this question. It seems to be a HUGE work to calculate the expression of the geodesics on this Riemannian space. Furthermore, I am wandering whether there is a proof of the completeness in Euclidean space with a arbitrary given metric. Any suggestion or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: To show a metric is not complete, all you need to do is find a single incomplete geodesic. In this case the symmetry means any straight line through the origin should be a geodesic, so you just need to work out the unit-speed parametrization.

Comment: I would approach this problem using the Hopf-Rinow theorem. You should be able to show that $(\mathbb{R}^n,g)$ is bounded, closed, and (certainly) not compact. The result will immediately follow. Let me know if you'd like me to write up an answer detailing this approach!

Comment: Treat the case of dimension ! The metric is $ds^2={1\over (1+K/4{x_1}^2)}{dx_1}^2$, is not complete on $\bf R$ as it has a finite length. Deduce that a geodesic cannot be extend..

Answer (score 2):

I have just got the answer for this particular metric, which is obviously isometric to the incomplete metric on sphere $\mathbb{S}^n\setminus{N}$ removing North Pole $N$ induced by stereographic projection with positive constant curvature $K$.